# What determines the depth of the .NET stack trace? (or, "Why don't I see the calling method in the stack trace?")

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a Windows Forms app written in VB.NET. I'm seeing an error in my logs like this:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.CustomNotification(ICustomDebuggerNotification data)
   at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.NotifyOfCrossThreadDependencySlow()
   at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.NotifyOfCrossThreadDependency()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at DBCTX.DBTask.AddTask(DBTaskTypeEnum TaskType, Nullable`1 ClientSurveyID, String Description, String SQL) in C:\Users\me\source\Workspaces\MyProj\Main\Foo\DB\Models\DBTask.vb:line 114
```

The problem is that I call AddTask from over 60 different places in my code. So I can't tell which one is triggering it. So my questions are:

1. Is there any way for me to get the stack trace to include a few more lines of context?
2. What determines the depth of the stack trace anyway? I.e. Why doesn't it go all the way back to main method of the app?

Comment: What you're seeing is everything that occurred on the thread on which the exception was thrown. You'd need some extra code on the thread that started that one in order to be notified there that a thread it started threw an exception. We can't tell you specifically what to do because we don't know how this thread is being started.

Comment: May be able to look at the inner exception if there is one could give you additional stack trace details.

Comment: is this a separate thread process you started (which of course does not have (yet) a call stack? as noted, you do normally get a call stack in such errors.

Comment: In this particular case, this was in a Windows Forms app and everything was happening in response to a button click. But there were multiple method calls prior to AddTask being called. That call itself is not happening on a separate thread. To my understanding this should have all happened on the main thread.

I don't know if there was an inner exception but if I can catch one of these I will check for that.

Comment: `AddTask` sounds to me like `I like to delegate this job to a background-thread`. Background-Threads have the problem that they are aborted when no foreground thread is active anymore (main windows closes and your task does not finish anymore).

Comment: It's just a naming coincidence. My AddTask method has nothing to do with the .NET Task class. It is not creating any threads.